# Make Main Thread to Wait for coroutine kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to compress an image in android but and I don't want to use `runBlocking`.
How can I make the main UI thread to wait for the compression to take place?
Currently, I am doing this

```
var compressedImage: File? = null
runBlocking {
    compressedImage = Compressor.compress(this@UpdateProfileActivity, cachedFile.absoluteFile)
}
camera = "gallery"
//doing something with the compressedImage.
```

**How to do it without `runBlocking`?**

Comment: You cannot make main thread wait without freezing your application, redesign your code so this block can be run in background context.

Comment: I can show a progressbar on main UI thread untill the process is getting completed any possible way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make the main-thread to wait for task completion. It causes freezing of your app until the main-thread gets free. You can do your long-running job in another thread, then switch to the main-thread to do whatever you want.

```
var compressedImage: File? = null
CoroutineScope().launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    compressedImage = Compressor.compress(this@UpdateProfileActivity, cachedFile.absoluteFile)
    
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        camera = "gallery"
        // doing something with the compressedImage.
    }
}
```